# Checking Vaild Email JavaScript Not working for me

Tags: javascript, html

Hey i need help to check if email is vaild email...
I tried it with javascript and i dont know how to do it... 
Can someone help me to make it please?

My HTML Code :

```html
<input type="text"name="email1" id="MyEmail" placeholder = "Your Email"/>
```

I want to make an javascript check that the email that the people write is vaild email and if not its will alert them... Please help

Answer (score 1):

> i want to check if the new member that want to register to my site is putted a date and that its not empty date (without putting numbers in the date box)

Example just using inline attribute `onblur`

```js
function check(text) {
  var msg = 'Empty';
  if (text.value.replace(/\s/g, '')) {
    msg = 'Not ' + msg;
  }
  console.log(msg, text.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="date" onblur="check(this)" />
<input type="date" onblur="check(this)" />
```

Above example attaching listeners

```js
let check = function(text) {
  var msg = 'Empty';
  if (text.value.replace(/\s/g, '')) {
    msg = 'Not ' + msg;
  }
  console.log(msg, text.value);
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="date"]').forEach(function(date) {
    date.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
      check(e.target);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="date" /><input type="date" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have add the `required` attribute to the input tag and remove the unnecessary slash after the max attribute like this:

```html
<form>
  <input type="date" id = "Date" min="1905-00-00" max="2019-00-00" required /><br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I dont get what you say bro, I mean i want to check if the member putted a date inside and if yes i want to return true.

Comment: Then you have to clarify that you're not talking about a form.

Comment: I am talking about register form

Comment: I dont understand your soulition, i want a javascript with if() that checking that my input date is not empty...

Comment: Then please clarify your question and post the code you already have made

Comment: @Roie: "*I don't understand your [solution]*" - then take the time to learn, and research (though admittedly it could be more fully explained); "*[I] want to check if the member [put] a date inside*" - then explain that in the question, but be aware that if you're going to ignore working answers just to satisfy your own lack of understanding you're going to have difficulty learning and improving.

Answer (score 0):

You can completely avoid and JavaScript by just adding a preset value to the date. This way users are forced to enter a date no matter what, because the input already starts with a given value. Here is the code:

```html
<input type="date" min="1905-00-00" max="2019-00-00" value="2018-01-01"/>
```

You can learn more here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_date_value.asp